# Should I accept an answer if it is very upvoted but I do not consider it is the correct answer to my question?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-answer, answer-quality, up-votes

That's the question. For example, imagine that you ask something and everyone answers with common industry superstitions or misconceptions...should I accept the very upvoted question (more than 50 upvotes for example) although I consider the answer is not the correct answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Absolutely not. If an answer does not address your question, then you do not have to accept it. People may upvote answers because they like it, or because they agree with the statements made, or whatever.

If you are asking about the answer I think you are asking about, in my opinion, it does not address your question at all, it only picks apart an example you provided.

In the end, you choose what answer meets your needs. If there isn't one, then consider placing a bounty on your question to get more attention on it.

Answer (score 11):

It's your question and you should choose the answer that you think is best. From the help page ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers):

> As the author of the question, you have an additional option: accepting an answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

The key words being *you believe*. If SE wanted the top-voted answer to always be accepted, the acceptance process would just be automated.

Answer (score 0):

The best part about this scenario is that you, as the question asker ,  get to revise your question / re-articulate it, so that your real need is expressed.

In fact, that is the whole reason that Jeff invented StackOverflow and related sites

http://blog.codinghorror.com/how-to-write-without-writing/